# Como funciona o minificador de codigo?

Tags: javascript, minificação

Estou perguntando isso porque eu fui minificar um JS e ele me deu um código que não entendi muito bem...

Meu código original:

```
$('input').each(function(a,b){if(b.value == "U"){$('.variacao-sku').remove()}});
```

O que ele me deu:

```
$("input").each(function(a,e){"U"==e.value&&$(".variacao-sku").remove()});
```

O código funcionou até, mas não entendi, ele não usou o if, verificou se a string "U" é igual a e.value e usou o operador && e removeu o item com o remove. Qual o sentido daquele `&&` ali?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essa técnica é chamada de curto circuito em expressões lógicas.

Quando você tem uma expressão lógica `A && B`, o resultado será verdadeiro se, e somente se, ambos operando forem verdadeiros, ou falso caso contrário. Assim, o interpretador irá primeiro avaliar o valor de `A`, se for considerado um valor falso, ele não precisará avaliar `B`, retornando `A`; se `A` for avaliado como verdadeiro, será retornado o valor de `B`, pois se `B` for falso, o resultado deverá ser falso e se verdadeiro deverá ser verdadeiro.

Portanto, na expressão:

```
"U" == e.value && $(".variacao-sku").remove()
```

O interpretador primeiro irá avaliar `"U" == e.value`, se for verdadeiro, irá avaliar (executar) `$(".variacao-sku").remove()`, produzindo o mesmo resultado que o código original:

```
if (b.value == "U") {
    $('.variacao-sku').remove()
}
```

Que é executar o `remove()` somente quando `b.value` for `"U"`.

Comment: Caramba, isso é muito, muito interessante. Obrigado por isso. (sem ironia)

Answer (score 2):

O seu código inicial já está mais ou menos minimizado, então o *minify* não alterou muito (formatação e nomes).

**Agora para a validação:**

O `&&` interrompe a validação assim que encontrar algo em desacordo e não continua verificando o resto.

Exemplo:

```
Se (1 == 2 && a == b) {}
```

Nesse caso, **em tempo de execução**, a instrução `a == b` nunca será executada, porque assim que o compilador ver que 1 não é igual a 2, ele vai sair do if e nem vai se preocupar com o que tem para frente.

Agora se você fizer:

```
Se (1 == 2 & a == b) {}
```

Nesse caso, em tempo de execução, as duas instruções serão verificadas e só depois o computador vai decidir o que deve ser feito.

É até recomendável usar sempre `&&` (ou `||`) para evitar processamento desnecessário.